# How to render output from react-html-email using React and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use [react-html-email](https://github.com/chromakode/react-html-email) to create email templates and the docs aren't clear on how to use renderEmail(emailComponent) can anyone point me in the right direction on how i'm supposed render the HTML output from this module using React and Webpack? The build process completes without errors but i dont see any HTML output and index.html is blank? Thanks!

Here is my Email component which renders the email template:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Email, Item, A} from 'react-html-email'

const BasicEmail = () => (

  <Email title='Basic Email'>
    <Item>
      <A href="#" style={{paddingLeft: 10}}>Hello World!</A>
    </Item>
  </Email>

);

export default BasicEmail;
```

Here is my Webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: ["./src/js/app.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "js/[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by adding renderEmail() inside of render() in app.js ... Running Webpack compiles the code to XHTML 1.0 Strict format then sends it to index.html

Here is my app.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {renderEmail} from 'react-html-email';
import BasicEmail from './../components/basicEmail'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      renderEmail(<BasicEmail />)
    );
  }
}

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the output of the `renderEmail` function and render it on screen in a react app, you would need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Here is an example. `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: emailHTML }} />;`

Comment: hey thanks for the reply ... im not actually trying to render the output to the screen this module is supposed to compile from React to HTML but i'm not getting any output files with the compiled HTML?

Comment: I don’t believe you’ll get files as output, I think you’d get your html as a string and that it’s ip to you to use however you want to.